# How to send XML request with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to retrieve data from [Google Apps Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reporting/#disk_space_report) which specify me to send XML request

My goal is to retrieve disk_space_report an put that data into spreadsheet so I can monitor the disk space in that spreadsheet and also process some data.

Anyone can give me an example on how to do that kind of stuff?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little code which I have written and using to fetch Google Apps users account report.

```
function startHere(){
  var domain = UserManager.getDomain();
  var fDate = '2012-12-18';//Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  var url = 'https://www.google.com/hosted/services/v1.0/reports/ReportingData';

  //Build API request parameters
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('Reporting', url);
  fetchArgs.method = 'POST';
  var rawXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
      +'<rest xmlns="google:accounts:rest:protocol" xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance ">'
      +'<type>Report</type>'
      +'<domain>'+domain+'</domain>'
      +'<date>'+fDate+'</date>'
      +'<page>1</page>'
      +'<reportType>daily</reportType>'
      +'<reportName>accounts</reportName>'
      +'</rest>';
  fetchArgs.payload = rawXML;
  fetchArgs.contentType = "application/xml";
  fetchArgs.headers = {"Content-type": "application/atom+xml charset=UTF-8"}; 

  //Fetch CSV data
  var csvData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText();

  //Parse CSV data and make a 2D array
  var recs = csvData.split('\n');
  var data = []; //this is actual 2D data
  for(var i=0; i<recs.length-1; i++){
    var temp = recs[i].split(',');
    if(i==0) temp.push('percent_disk_usage');
    else{
      var usage = (parseInt(temp[5])*100)/(parseInt(temp[4])*1024*1024);
      temp.push(usage);
    }
    data.push(temp);
  }
//Write data to spreadsheet
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick sample. Inside your script create a new HTML file called: xmlRequest with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rest xmlns="google:accounts:rest:protocol"
    xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance ">
        <type>Report</type>
    <domain>YOURDOMAIN.COM</domain>
      <date>2012-12-01</date>
        <page>1</page>
        <reportType>daily</reportType>
        <reportName>accounts</reportName>
</rest>
```

Change YOURDOMAIN.COM with your Google Apps domain. Inside Code.gs paste the following code:

```
/**
 * Script configuration
 */
var SCOPE = 'https://www.google.com/hosted/services/v1.0/reports/ReportingData';
var APPNAME = "disk_space_report";
var URL = 'https://www.google.com/hosted/services/v1.0/reports/ReportingData';

function testit() {
  // Generate the new entry from a template
  var template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("xmlRequest").getContent();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL,googleOAuth_('POST', template));
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}


/**
 * Google authentication loader
 * @param {String} method the HTTP method to use for the UrlFetch operation, possible values are: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
 * @param {String} payload the payload to use if needed
 * @return {Object} configuration options for UrlFetch, including oAuth parameters
 */
function googleOAuth_(method, payload) {
  // Shared configuration for all methods
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(APPNAME);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope='+encodeURIComponent(SCOPE));
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken');
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');

  // Detect the required method
  switch(method) {
    case "GET":
      return {oAuthServiceName:APPNAME, oAuthUseToken:'always'};
      break;
    case "POST":
      return {oAuthServiceName:APPNAME, oAuthUseToken:'always', payload: payload, contentType: 'application/atom+xml', method: "POST"};
      break;
    case "PUT":
      return {oAuthServiceName:APPNAME, oAuthUseToken:'always', payload: payload, contentType: 'application/atom+xml', method: "PUT"};
      break;
    case "DELETE":
      return {oAuthServiceName:APPNAME, oAuthUseToken:'always', method: "DELETE"};
      break;
    default:
      return {oAuthServiceName:APPNAME, oAuthUseToken:'always'};
      break;
  }
}
```

Now run the testit function and inside the logger you should get the raw disk usage stats to get parsed.